# bootstrap cover template: where to place image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a complete newbie question, but:

**Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)'s [cover template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/), how/where should I insert the background image to cover the page?**

What I am I missing? I have tried inserting the  inside the following elements in the template

```
 <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
 <div class="cover-container">
 <div class="inner cover">
```

the image is shown but not sized to fill the viewport's dimensions.

(Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of this template?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on where the background image is applied, it looks like the background is applied to the body tag. In which case apply this CSS:

```
body { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

"cover" causes the background to fill the block element.

Answer (score 0):

It should go in:

```
html,
body {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you place it with in `body` you will have small margin.